# How do I use nested SELECT query to populate SET variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I/How do I use a SELECT query to populate a variable using SET, when I need to SELECT the data from another SELECT statement (hope that makes sense?) that already includes joined tables. I've tried different arrangements of the brackets but keep getting syntax errors. Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I'm basically trying to set the default of the Lead statement to this variable. Or find another way to get the data from one.quitdate into the enddate column when there is a NULL value in the enddate column.

```
DECLARE @quitdatevar DATETIME

SET @quitdatevar = (SELECT one.quitdate 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              one.ID, [other columns], two.startdate, 
              LEAD(two.startdate, 1, @quitdatevar) OVER (PARTITION BY 
              (one.ID) ORDER BY (one.ID)) AS enddate, one.quitdate
           FROM 
               [table1] AS one 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    [table2] AS two ON two.ID = one.ID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             [table3] AS three ON three.ID = two.ID 
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN
            WHERE  
                 [bunch of conditions] ) AS subq) 
            ORDER BY
                 [column1], [column2]
```

In the end I should have a table looking like this (yes, my example doesn't make sense in the real world) :

| ID | [other]... | startdate | enddate | quitdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

- `ID` - think of it like an employee ID
- `Startdate` - shift starts at startdate date/time
- `Enddate` - shift ends at the startdate date/time of the next row (if same ID)
- `Quitdate` - if enddate is NULL then it pulls a date from the current ID's quitdate, which was stored using the variable @quitdatevar(default of Lead statement)

Comment: This is almost legal T-SQL already, it's just that you're required to give your subqueries a name. Put a `_` after the `)` to "name" it and Bob, as they say, is your uncle. Note that you *can* remove a level of nesting by just writing `SELECT @quitdatevar = [one.quitdate] FROM ...`, but I do not recommend it, because the `SET` syntax will detect and error on the case where your query returns more than one result, while the latter will just pick an arbitrary value (which can lead to results that are hard to debug and reproduce). In that vein: I think you forgot a `TOP(1)`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! I added ") AS subq)" to end of WHERE clause.  Now I get "The multi-part identifier "one.quitdate" could not be bound." error.  I've tried replacing the 'one' part of the name with the full table name and get the same error.

Comment: @jarlh -- I use SSMS for my querying, so I don't need to specify the dbm (it assumes it), so I just use the table/column names in my sample

Comment: Right, because the column name is now `subq.quitdate`. You can't access the base tables outside the subquery.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Fixed the error by using the AS name instead of the table name.  But now I understand why you mentioned missing the TOP (1) after I got the "subquery returned more than 1 value" error.  I don't believe I can do what I want with this subquery. I will need to completely restructure it.  Not sure what to do.  I need all the rows from the subquery to display but want the variable to grab data from the quitdate.

Comment: *I need all the rows from the subquery* so use the subquery: either through a join or via `where ??? IN(subquery here)` and don't bother with the variable at all